# django startapp admin file missing

Tags: django

I've been following the DjangoProject tutorial.  When I run 
`python manage.py startapp newapp`
while in the same directory as `manage.py`. In the newapp directory I see `init.py`, `models.py`, `tests.py`, and `views.py` but not `admin.py` file. Where is `admin.py`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create it yourself.

edit:

Currently only the development version of Django creates an `admin.py` file within a new app.

Comment: No, its supposed to create it when i run startapp. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models

Comment: @brno792 What is the django version you are using?

Comment: Ah indeed it does, but that's only in the development version at the moment.

Comment: @brno792 Refer version specific documentation.

Comment: is this a recent change? i dont recall having this issue a few months ago. im usiing version 1.4.3

Comment: Yes, it was added less than a month ago (on the 29th January) by Aymeric Augustin, see here: https://github.com/django/django/commit/3f1c7b#L0R1